# Extracting a Link from a String using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

First off what I am trying to do is ask the user for a search term. The program then searches yahoo and prints out the link of the first result. Here's the code I have so far.

```
from urllib import urlopen

import re, time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


print "What Would You Like to Search For?"

user_input = raw_input('') #Gets Search Term from User



search = "http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A2KLtaJX_1BQfT4AwX2bvZx4?p=baker&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-701" 

new_search = search.replace('baker', user_input)           
content = urlopen( new_search ).read()                       

soupcontent = BeautifulSoup(content)                    


link1 = soupcontent.find(id="link-1")            
print link1
```

Everything works fine. It takes the user input and searches Yahoo.
The problem I'm having is lets say I searched for 'dog'

the program would then print something like this:

  "a id="link-1" class="yschttl spt" href="http://www.dog.com/" data-bk="5101.1>b>Dog/b> Supplies | b>Dog/b> Food, b>Dog/b> Beds, b>Dog/b> wbr>/wbr>Flea Control & More .../a>"

Which Is indeed the first Link on the page. However I would only like it to print out "http://www.dog.com/" Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried using that However i get this error

Comment: did you try regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup actually makes this very easy:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> 
>>> url = 'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=dog'
>>> content = urlopen(url).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
>>> 
>>> soup.find(id="link-1")
<a class="yschttl spt" data-bk="5097.1" href="http://www.dog.com/" id="link-1"><b>Dog</b> Supplies | <b>Dog</b> Food, <b>Dog</b> Beds, <b>Dog</b> <wbr></wbr>Flea Control &amp; More ...</a>
>>> soup.find(id="link-1").get("href")
'http://www.dog.com/'
```

With your request for UTF-8 you'll probably see

```
 u'http://www.dog.com/'
```

instead, the Unicode version, which is fine too.

Standard warning: be sure to check that Yahoo!'s end-user license permits whatever you want to do, because many licenses rule out certain automated uses.

Comment: Thank You DSM. I'd Being trying to do with Soup for hours. I tried many variations and none of them worked however .get("href")
did. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression.  See: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html.

```
match = re.search(r'href="(http://.*?)"', str(link1))
print match.group(1)
```

Comment: He wants the http to be printed though so shouldn't it be r'href="(.*?)"' instead?

Comment: No I dont have much experience with programming at all. I tried using that but i get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 25, in <module>
    match = re.search(r'"http://(.*?)"', link1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @moretimetocry Pna's answer will also work and is maybe simpler. Using regular expressions can be somewhat tricky.

Comment: I like DSM's solution better than mine, so please follow his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`link = your_full_link_string.split('href="')[1].split('"')[0]`